# How to choose the OpenGL context for QtQuick applications

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qtquick2

I am writing an QtQuick application, mainly in QML, but I have some parts that use OpenGL more directly (an OpenSceneGraph scene). For some reasons, I want to use OpenGL version >= 3.3, but Qt only choose a 3.0 implementation. My code is:

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Create the app.
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Start the UI.
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl("main.qml"));

    return app.exec();
}
```

`main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
  id: root
  width: 800
  height: 600
  title: "App"

  visible: true

  Label {
    text: "OpenGL: " + OpenGLInfo.majorVersion + ' ' + OpenGLInfo.minorVersion + OpenGLInfo.profile
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you reading about the existence of OpenGL 3.4 & 3.5?

Comment: What do you mean? I know I have a sufficiently new implementation of OpenGL on my computer (i.e. Mesa up to OpenGL 4.5), and some of my GLSL shaders needs GLSL 3.30 to be built, for example.

Comment: I'm alluding to the fact that OpenGL 3.4 & 3.5 [*don't exist*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL#Version_history).  It goes from 3.3 right to 4.0.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I meant 3.3. But it doesn't change my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it is to set the default QSurfaceFormat **before** the `app.exec()`.

```
#include <QSurfaceFormat>

...

QSurfaceFormat surfaceFormat;
surfaceFormat.setMajorVersion(3);
surfaceFormat.setMinorVersion(3);
surfaceFormat.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(surfaceFormat);
```